# show only next line after the matched one with sed

Tags: sed

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7451478/15603477

I understand `grep -A1 'blah' logfile | grep -v "blah"`

but I don't understand `sed -n '/blah/{n;p;}' logfile`
So far I checked manual sed command line option page:  https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html.
There is only `-n` means quiet.
obviously `/blah/` refer to the pattern `/blah/` then hard to understand part is `{n;p;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally sed prints whatever is in the `pattern space` at the end of processing. The `-n` option disables this printing so only explicit print requests produce output.

The program `/blah/{n;p;}` says "If the line matches `blah`, then do the `n` and `p` commands". `n` says "read the next line into the `pattern space`" and the `p` says "print the `pattern space`".

Note that this sed program produces different results the the `grep -A1 "blah" | grep -v "blah"` for the case where there are consecutive lines containing `blah`. The `grep` pair will never output a line with `blah`, but the sed can. Also the output of the grep pair can contain `==` that the first grep introduces to divide blocks.